# Even a very simple program to help you get the following error

Tags: android

Even the most simple code in my spelling as I mentioned in the title of what I do , I get this error Have the necessary bi INFORMATION What is the line ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.anasayfa);

        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);

       gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri link = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.tr");
                Intent tara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, link);
                startActivity(tara);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c){
            mContext =c;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if(convertView==null){
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
            }else{
                imageView=(ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        private Integer [] mThumbIds={
                R.drawable.sondakika,R.drawable.yoklogo,R.drawable.universiteler,R.drawable.sondakika
        };
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
    08-20 13:57:40.821    7257-7257/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
    08-20 13:57:41.425    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    08-20 13:57:41.429    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 406: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    08-20 13:57:41.433    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    08-20 13:57:41.437    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    08-20 13:57:41.441    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 428: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    08-20 13:57:41.445    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    08-20 13:57:41.561    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 147K, 6% free 3684K/3892K, paused 34ms, total 40ms
    08-20 13:57:41.605    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 6% free 3901K/4116K, paused 16ms, total 18ms
    08-20 13:57:41.693    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.286MB for 2536932-byte allocation
    08-20 13:57:41.701    7257-7268/com.example.abdullah.deneme D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 6378K/6596K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
    08-20 13:57:41.725    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    08-20 13:57:41.729    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d2db20)
    08-20 13:57:41.733    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.abdullah.deneme, PID: 7257
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abdullah.deneme/com.example.abdullah.deneme.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
                at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:774)
                at com.example.abdullah.deneme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-20 13:57:45.065    7257-7257/com.example.abdullah.deneme I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 7257 SIG: 9

        Process: com.example.abdullah.deneme, PID: 7257
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abdullah.deneme/com.example.abdullah.deneme.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
                at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:774)
                at com.example.abdullah.deneme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: *Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead* raised from `gridView.setOnClickListener()`. What's unclear about that message?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there error and fix is _very clearly_ shown in the logcat.

Comment: yes a simple mistake could be for you.yet it may be difficult for me in the way you're free to do what you want , but I do not understand that English is not enough skin in logchat Thanks to everyone who responded .

Answer (score 0):

Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead.

Over here:

```
gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);

   gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Change that according to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Error :

> ```
>      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead.
> ```

Change

```
gridView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri link = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.tr");
                Intent tara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, link);
                startActivity(tara);
            }
        });
```

to

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
               Uri link = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.tr");
                Intent tara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, link);
                startActivity(tara);

            }
        });
```